# dmidecode showing less Memory Capacity than Motherboard spec?

Tags: memory, supermicro

We got a supermicro server, http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1u/5016/sys-5016i-ur.cfm, according spec, the server supports up to 32G memory when using ECC Register Memory.

However, when I tried the dmidecode command, it says 24G max memory:

```
[root@c1 ~]# dmidecode | grep Maximum
Maximum Size: 256 kB
Maximum Size: 1024 kB
Maximum Size: 8192 kB
Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096 MB
Maximum Total Memory Size: 24576 MB
Maximum Capacity: 24 GB
Maximum Value: Unknown
```

Which one I should trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust the manufacturer. But the [supported memory arrangements](http://www.supermicro.com/products/Memory/3400_support.cfm?pname=SYS-5016I-URF&DIMM=6) are quite complex, so be careful. For example, the only way to get 32GB is with 4 x 8GB [*Quad Rank*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank) RDIMMs.

Comment: Great. Looked supermicro supported memory page, I have 4x4G RDIMM already, does that mean I can't simply add 2 x 8G to get to 32G?